# Efficiently solving the same matrix multiple times in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a program that involves solving a fairly large matrix, ~3000^2, multiple times at each time step. The matrix stays the same, but the right have side varies, e.g. I solve Ax=b, Ax=c etc. At the moment I am just naively using backslash as many times are there are matrix equations I need to solve, even though the matrix is the same at any given time step. Is there a way to take advantage of the matrix staying the same to speed things up?

Comment: Perhaps share your code?

Comment: Try `A\[b c]`. It should be faster than doing `A\b` and `A\c`

Answer (score 1):

```
A\b
```

is the same as

```
inv(A)*b
```

although the former is typically recommended because it provides more precise results and has less trouble for certain types of `A`. But if the latter is good enough for your application, then by all means pre-compute `inv(A)`. It will save a lot of time when solving many equations as in this case.

Comment: I had just assumed inv(A) will be slower, but I'll do a time test. I solve 6 matrix equations with the same matrix at each time step.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MATLAB after R2017b, check out the [decomposition object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/decomposition.html).  It will create a re-usable factorization of your matrix that will make subsequent linear solves more efficient.  In particular, check out the first example on the doc page, which compares using the decomposition object to performing a series of linear solves.